# how to use swift function loadLeaderboardSetsWithCompletionHandler

Tags: ios, swift, gamekit, game-center-leaderboard

```
GKLeaderboardSet.loadLeaderboardSetsWithCompletionHandler(_ completionHandler: (([GKLeaderboardSet]?,NSError?) -> Void)?)
```

I'm trying to use this class function to retrieve the information of the leaderboard sets from Game Center.

```
            var leaderboardSetsRetrived = [""]
        GKLeaderboardSet.loadLeaderboardSetsWithCompletionHandler({ (leaderboardSets, error) -> Void in
            leaderboardSetsRetrived = leaderboardSets
        })
```

This is what I tried to do, but xcode says

> "Cannot convert value of type '([String], _) -> Void' to expected argument type '(([GKLeaderboardSet]?, NSError?) -> Void)?"

What should I put for the parameters?

What Game Center Programming Guide told me to do:

> Before you can load the leaderboards contained within a set, you must load the set itself. Retrieve the list of leaderboard sets for your game from Game Center and display their titles. Use the loadLeaderboardSetsWithCompletionHandler: method to retrieve the leaderboard sets for your app. You can then load the leaderboards for a specific leaderboard set using the loadLeaderboardsWithCompletionHandler: method.

```
@available(iOS 7.0, *)
public class GKLeaderboardSet : NSObject, NSCoding, NSSecureCoding {

    public var title: String { get } // Localized set title.

    public var groupIdentifier: String? { get } // set when leaderboardSets have been designated a game group; set when loadLeaderboardSetsWithCompletionHandler has been called for leaderboards that support game groups
    public var identifier: String? // leaderboard set.

    // Loads array with all sets for game
    // Possible reasons for error:
    // 1. Communications problem
    // 2. Unauthenticated player
    // 3. Set not present
    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    public class func loadLeaderboardSetsWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler: (([GKLeaderboardSet]?, NSError?) -> Void)?)

    // Loads array with all leaderboards for the leaderboardSet
    // Possible reasons for error:
    // 1. Communications problem
    // 2. Unauthenticated player
    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    public func loadLeaderboardsWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler: (([GKLeaderboard]?, NSError?) -> Void)?)
}

extension GKLeaderboardSet {

    // Asynchronously load the image. Error will be nil on success.

    public func loadImageWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler: ((UIImage?, NSError?) -> Void)?)
}
```

code from GKLeaderboardSet.h

Now my code is working.

```
GKLeaderboardSet.loadLeaderboardSetsWithCompletionHandler({ (leaderboard, error) -> Void in
            })
```

But the function isn't receiving any parameters for some reason. I can't save the `leaderboardSets` that's supposed to be retrieved to a variable that I created.  According to the GKLeaderboard Class Reference:

> Parameters:

```
completionHandler
```

> A block that is called when the categories have been retrieved from the server.
>
> The block receives the following parameters:
>
> `leaderboardSets`
>   An array of `GKLeaderboardSet` objects that provides the leaderboard sets for your game. If an error occurred, this value may be non-nil. In this case, the array holds whatever data Game Kit was able to download before the error occurred.
>
> `error`
>   If an error occurred, this error object describes the error. If the operation completed successfully, the value is nil.

Comment: Could you post the relative code about `leaderboardSets` ?

Comment: Your code looks good. Maybe you have an older version of Xcode that doesn't accept the closure that way. I tried this same code using Xcode 7.2.1 and it compiles with no issues.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm currently using Xcode 7.2, will try again after updating to 7.2.1

Comment: nope, still not working after updating to 7.2.1. same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed now. A mistake I made: `leaderboardSetsRetrieved` should be `[GKLeaderboardSet]` instead of a string array. Second, for some reason `leaderboardSetsRetrived = leaderboardSets` does work, it's just that Xcode doesn't auto complete `leaderboardSets` for some reason and I thought there's something wrong with the parameter.